# android.process.acore crash loop when removing accounts

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, crashes

I am currently running rooted stock android 4.4.2 on Galaxy S4 (i9500). Oddly enough EVERY time I remove an account (mostly tested with google) I trigger an android.process.acore crash loop. (Which always leads to loss of contacts due to the solution nature)

I know I can fix the crash loop by clearing contact storage data, but is there any way to prevent the error on account removal in the first place?